# Using System.Func anonymous and the return object with callback function

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Maybe simple question but how can I get the return object of a asynchronously System.Func?

Consider this:

```
private void Start(String a)
{
    System.Func<String, objectA> callasync = delegate(String strA)
    {
        return bla(stra);  // Which return a objectA
    }

    callasync.BeginInvoke(a, callback, null);
}

private void callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Here I want the objectA but how ??
}
```

With callback function, I didn't have the delegate signature. And of course, i can create a delegate in scope of the class but maybe is there a solution to read the return value in the callback function.

Thank.

Comment: FYI - Your Func can be rewritten more concisely:

Comment: Func<string, objectA> callasync = strA => bla(strA);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `BeginInvoke` on a delegate, the `IAsyncResult` of passed to the callback will be an instance of the `AsyncResult` class. From that you can get an instance of your delegate and call `EndInvoke` on it.

```
private void Start(string a)
{
    Func<string, objectA> d = strA => bla(strA);

    d.BeginInvoke(a, Callback, null);
}

private void Callback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
     AsyncResult asyncResult = (AsyncResult)ar;
     Func<string, objectA> d = (Func<string, objectA>)asyncResult.AsyncDelegate;
     objectA result = d.EndInvoke(ar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this (not written in IDE, may contain errors)

```
  private Func<String, objectA> _callDoWorkAsync = DoWork;
  private static string DoWork( objectA strA )
  {
     return bla( strA );
  }

  private void Start( String a )
  {
     _callDoWorkAsync.BeginInvoke( a, callback, null );
  }

  private void callback( IAsyncResult ar )
  {
     objectA strA = (objectA) _callDoWorkAsync.EndInvoke( ar );
  }
```